# Empty database table laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I don't know why am I getting an empty table. In the past, it was working for me but why am I getting this now? What I am doing wrong?

**Controller:** AdminServiceController

```php
public function create()
{
    return view("admin.service.create");
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $date = $this->vvalidate($request);
    $data['creator'] = auth()->user()->id;
    Services::create($data);
}

private function vvalidate($request)
{
    $rules = [
        'title' => 'required|unique:services',
        'description' => 'required|min:100',
    ];
    
    return $this->validate($request, $rules);
}
```

**Model:** Services.php

```php
class Services extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

**Routes:** web.php

```php
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::name('admin.')->group(function () {
        Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
            Route::get('/', function () {
                return view('admin');
            });
            Route::resource('service', 'App\Http\Controllers\AdminServiceController');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: are you getting an error thrown?

Comment: I have the solution. Wrote $date instead of $data. I feel like a dunce haha

Comment: `protected $guarded = [];` yolo right....

Comment: Also in `store` method `vvalidate` instead of `validate`

Answer (score 0):

> AdminServiceController

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  { 
    Services::create($this->vvalidate($request));
  }

  private function vvalidate($request)
  {
    $data = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|unique:services',
        'description' => 'required|min:100',
    ]);
    $data['creator'] = auth()->user()->id;
    return $data;
  }
```

> Services.php

```
 protected $fillable = [
   'title', 'description'
];
```